# Javascript check if target contains class with switch-case instead of if else

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement

Currently I have a code structure:

```
if(target.classList.contains('animate-heading')){

}else if(target.classList.contains('animate-text')){

}else if(target.classList.contains('animate-buttons')){

}else if(target.classList.contains('image-rotating-animation')){

}else if(target.classList.contains('plans-heading-animation')){

}else if(target.classList.contains('plans-animation')){

}else if(target.classList.contains('animate-masonry')){

}
```

which I want to replace with switch-case statements, is it possible to do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not really because switch runs on a string matching and you are not matching a string. It could be done, but would be almost exactly the same thing you have.

Comment: "*which I want to replace with switch-case statements*" - why would you want to do that? It's not like `switch` is cleaner here.

Comment: What is the actual code content of these conditional blocks?

Answer (score 1):

Switch checks for an exact match so there is nothing you really could do to match it. You could do it as a truthy check in a switch, but it does not make it any cleaner than the if/else if

```
const classList = target.classList

switch (true) {
  case classList.contains('animate-heading'):
  break;
  case classList.contains('animate-text'):
  break;
}
```

Comment: This looks actually a good solution. One benefit of switch over "if/else if" is that switch will allow fall-through from one case to another, if you leave the break statement out.